# How to replace or delete None at parser(python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I'm parsing a website with BeautifulSoup I get:

```
None
offer_15542518
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

The code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
projects =[]
table = soup.find('table', class_='objects_items_list')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    internal_id = row.get('id')
    print( internal_id )
```

How to get rid of the `None`? I need just the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
projects =[]
table = soup.find('table', class_='objects_items_list')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    internal_id = row.get('id')
    if internal_id is not None:
        print( internal_id )
```

The simplest way is just to check if `internal_id` is None and print it only if it's not.